# How can I check if my script works fine on different python versions

Tags: python

I have a python script that I wrote and it's works just fine.
My python version is 3.9.2.
There is a way to check if my script will work without any problems on Python 3.7?

Thank you for the help!
Have a great day

Comment: The most foolproof way is to write a unit test and run the test with Python 3.7.

Comment: You can also create a virtual environment (venv) with Python3.7 to check and confirm your program.